# Cохранение в файл массивов, объектов класса и других данных

Tags: массивы, файлы, классы, c++, visual-c++

Добрый день! Я пишу курсовую "Тетрис" в консольном режиме. Встал вопрос, как реализовать сохранение и загрузку в игре. Сохранять придётся двумерный массив, объекты класса и простые переменные. Вопрос в следующем: если я открыл файл для записи и поочерёдно буду записывать переменные, то куда они будут добавляться, в конец файла? И второй вопрос: если я хочу записать массив или объект класса, то я должен поочерёдно записать все элементы массива или поля объекта класса и в соответствующем порядке потом считывать?
Буду очень благодарен за пример кода с сохранением трёхмерного массива методом С++.

Заранее спасибо за ответы! Р.S. Я новичок тут, если что не так, простите.

Comment: А Вы не ленитесь и просто попробуйте. 

Догадка 

     ...должен поочердно записать все елементы массива или поля объекта класса.. и в соответствующем порядке потом считывать...

верна.